# Add items to Json

Tags: json, kotlin

I have a problem for a long time that I would like to solve:
I have a fragment with buttons, that when I press a button I have the variable * data that happened to the url I want to open.

```
val  button01 = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_01) as Button
button01.setOnClickListener{
dato = "01"
miTexto.setText("Jornada - 01")
    requestJsonObject()
 }
```

My url

```
val url = Directions.JORNADAS + Directions.CMP + "&jor=$dato&tmp=" + Directions.TMP
```

This url is clear that he opens it to me, it is a json which I pause and I already pass to the adapter and shows it to me.

From the adapter I pass data, which come in the Json with a put.extras intent, to the activity details.kt which depends on the item that pulse shows me the data of another url.

```
val intent = Intent(context, Detalles::class.java
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{  
     intent.putExtra("nomLocal", jornada.nomLocal)context.startActivity(intent)......
```

Up here all good.

My problem: I need to pass the variable data to the activity Details.kt to be able to access the url, since * data is a piece of url of what I am going to parse in the activity Details

I had thought about adding an item to the Json

```
private fun requestJsonObject() {

    val queue = newRequestQueue(activity)

    //http://www.ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/server.php?action=getResultados&cmp=328&jor=1&tmp=2018/2019

val url = Directions.JORNADAS + Directions.CMP + "&jor=$dato&tmp=" + Directions.TMP

val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->

val builder = GsonBuilder()
        val mGson = builder.create()

        val items: List<ModelJor>

        items = Arrays.asList(*mGson.fromJson(response, Array<ModelJor>::class.java))

        items.add(ModelJor("\"jornada\":" + $dato)) // dato en rojo
Log.d("Resultado", items.toString())

        recyclerView !!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!, 1)

        val adapter = AdapJor(activity !!, items)
        recyclerView !!.adapter = adapter

    }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.message) })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
 }
```

Any solution?

Comment: Paste more code. What is `items`, what is `AdapJor` constructor

Comment: @Andrey Turkovsky post 1 edited